# Migrating all the Kusto database principals to a different database on a different Kusto cluster

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a database D1 on the cluster C1 and I have a bunch of (maybe 100) principals defined on D1. Now assume that I also have another database D2 on the cluster C2. Also I am admin on both the databases. Is there any way I can just script out all my service principals and execute that script in one shot against D2 and thus achieve migration of all the principals? If not, is there any other way of achieving this, other than explicitly granting permission to each one of the principals against the database D2? (that will be like executing a hundred commands)

Answer (score 1):

There's no current way of exporting/importing database-level principals from one database to another.

One option for you to consider is writing a simple app/script (using [Kusto's API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/)) that:

1. Lists all principals using `.show database ['database_name'] principals`
2. Generates a list of `.add database ['database_name'] <role> (<principal>)` commands based on 1. (or a single command per role, were  is a comma-separated list of principals)
3. Runs all commands from 2.

Comment: the problem is that I can't run multiple commands in Kusto Explorer in batch mode, I have to run one lined at a time, keeping rest of the commands commented out and basically do the same thing maybe a hundred times.

Comment: hence my recommendation to write a simple script/app that does that - using Kusto's API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/